# Autoresizing on load in AgGrid React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, ag-grid

I am following the tutorial [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-grid/column-sizing/)

We have a redux application which populates the Ag-Grid when the server API is called. In the example it gives `autoSizeAll` as an explicit button. Is there a way to have autoResizeAll inside `onGridReady`.

I tried to do that but `gridColumnApi` is comming as null inside `onGridReady`

```
const onGridReady = (params) => {
        setGridApi(params.api)
        setGridColumnApi(params.columnApi)
     
        var allColumnIds = []
        gridColumnApi.getAllColumns().forEach(function (column) {
            allColumnIds.push(column.colId)
        })
        gridColumnApi.autoSizeColumns(allColumnIds, false) //skipHeader
    }
```

Comment: gridColumnApi is null because the state update using the updater provided by useState hook is asynchronous, and will not be reflected immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Resizing Columns When Data Is Rendered
There are two main scenarios where you might want to resize columns based on grid data:

- Row Data is available at grid initialisation
- Row Data is available
  after grid initialisation, typically after data has been set
  asynchronously via a server call

In the first case you can fire autoSizeColumns() in either the gridReady or the firstDataRendered event as the row data will have been rendered by the time the grid is ready.

In the second case however you can only reliably use firstDataRendered as the row data will be made available, and hence rendered, after the grid is ready.

In your case you need to use onFirstDataRenderer callback because data is fetched from the API.

For example:

```
const onGridReady = (params) => {
    setGridApi(params.api)
    setGridColumnApi(params.columnApi)
}

const onFirstDataRendered = (params) => {
    var allColumnIds = []
    gridColumnApi.getAllColumns().forEach(function (column) {
        allColumnIds.push(column.colId)
    })
    gridColumnApi.autoSizeColumns(allColumnIds, false) //skipHeader
}
```